# Abnormal width when I have two graph D3.js on the same page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, force-layout, bubble-chart

I have a problem when there is two graph on same page, the first graph has a normal size but the second which is populated by fixed data is anormaly large. The two graph are superimposed. Strange thing, if I use the code of the second graph, it works on my local website test. 
This is the code of the second graph :

```
// http://blog.thomsonreuters.com/index.php/mobile-patent-suits-graphic-of-the-day/
    var links = [
        {"source":"TEST111","target":"TEST222","level":"1","life":"1","test":"1","type":"licensing"},
        {"source":"TEST222","target":"TEST3333","level":"2","life":"2","test":"2","type":"licensing"},
        {"source":"TEST3333","target":"TEST4444","level":"3","life":"3","test":"3","type":"licensing"}
    ];

    var nodes = {};

    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.

    links.forEach(function(link) {
        link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, level:link.level, life:link.life});
        link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, level:link.level, life:link.life});
    });

    var width = 960,
            height = 500;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
            .links(links)
            .size([width, height])
            .linkDistance(200)
            .charge(-400)
            .on("tick", tick)
            .start();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
            .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
            .enter().append("marker")
            .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 15)
            .attr("refY", -1.5)
            .attr("markerWidth", 20)
            .attr("markerHeight", 20)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
            .data(force.links())
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
            .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

    var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", 20)
            .call(force.drag)
            .style("fill","red")
            .on("click", click);
    function click(d){


    }

    var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("x", 8)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
    function tick() {
        path.attr("d", linkArc);
        circle.attr("transform", transform);
        text.attr("transform", transform)
    }

    function linkArc(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    }

    function transform(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }
```

Also, on the Pluker, the two graph are bunk but it's not the problem (It works in local). You can delete the data load if you want (line 34). This is an online Plunker to see the problem : https://plnkr.co/edit/ewoi6wao97tXAKr1QxIm?p=preview
Thanks.

Comment: Check the plnkr now : https://plnkr.co/edit/ndKAArG5uYJEcKSeqG1R?p=preview whats the problem exactly ? I have just changed the diameter to 250 so I could see both graphs

Comment: The problem is the size of Layout diagram, It should be like that : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your problem was you were filling the path rather than just giving it a stroke.

So when you create the path just add the following :

```
  .style("fill","none").style("stroke","red")
```

So now it looks like :

```
  var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
            .data(force.links())
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
            .style("fill","none").style("stroke","red")
            .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });
```

Updated plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/JgHwC4zyolj0hsg8ib4w?p=preview

Comment: It's works, thanks but can you explain me with more details ? Thanks.

Comment: Basically the path you are creating is a curve between two points. So at the moment you are filling the curce, i.e fill under the curve and between the two points which gives you what you previously had. Now if you just have the stroke, all you see is the curve you want :) Understand ?

Comment: Ok but why if we don't define the .style (the exactly same code which have problems with other graph), It works on a single web page ? It could be the stroke take .style and size of graph ?

Comment: Ok I just understand ! It was as you said basically a .style problem. I forgotten to add this code as in the example: `<style>.link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #666;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }#licensing {
        fill: green;
    }.link.licensing {
        stroke: green;
    }.link.resolved {
        stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
    }circle {
        fill: #ccc;
        stroke: #333;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        pointer-events: none;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;}</style>`